# Understanding formula for OEIS A334742: a(A033638(n)) = a(A002620(n))

Tags: oeis

How do I interpret the formula for OEIS A334742 (https://oeis.org/A334742), which is given as:

$$a(A033638(n)) = a(A002620(n)) \,\,\mathrm{for}\,\, n > 1.$$

Since

$$A002620(n)= \Bigl\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\Bigr\rfloor$$

and

$$A033638(n) = A002620(n)+1 =  \Bigl\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\Bigr\rfloor+1,$$

it seems we have:

$$a( \Bigl\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\Bigr\rfloor+1) = a( \Bigl\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\Bigr\rfloor) \,\,\mathrm{for}\,\, n > 1.$$

Comment: For $n>1$ , we have 
$$\underbrace{a\left( \lfloor \frac{2^2}{4} \rfloor +1\right)}_{a(2)} = a\left( \lfloor \frac{2^2}{4}\rfloor \right) = a(1)=1$$
Again 
$$a(3)=a\left( \lfloor \frac{3^2}{4} \rfloor+1\right)=a\left( \lfloor \frac{3^2}{4} \rfloor\right) = a(2)=1 $$
and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $\left\{\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\right\rfloor\right\}=\{0,1,2,4,6,9,12,16,20,25,\ldots\}$

So your final line tells us:
$$\begin{align}
&a(1)=a(0)\\
&a(2)=a(1)=a(0)\\
&a(3)=a(2)=a(1)=a(0)\\
&a(5)=a(4)\\
&a(7)=a(6)\\
&a(10)=a(9)\\
&a(13)=a(12)\\
&a(17)=a(16)\\
&a(21)=a(20)\\
&a(26)=a(25)
\end{align}$$

That is, it tells us some members of $a(n)$ are equal to other members.

Note that it says nothing about certain members like $a(8)$. And it doesn't say anything about how $a(3)$ and $a(4)$ relate to each other (for example).

Comment: So would it be correct to say that the formula underdetermines the sequence?

Comment: I think that would be a fair thing to say.